# Help me to find out

Tags: trigger

I want create number of contacts which are equal to the the number which we will enter in the number of locations field.

```
trigger ContactsCreation on Account (after insert) {

list<contact>listcon = new list<contact>();
map<id,decimal> mapacc = new map<id,decimal>();
for(account acc:Trigger.new){
mapacc.put(acc.id, acc.Number_Of_Locations__c);
system.debug('xxxxxx'+mapacc);
}

if(mapacc.size()>0&&mapacc!=null){

for(id accid:mapacc.keyset()){

for(integer i=0;i<mapacc.get(accid);i++){

contact newContact = new contact();
newContact.accountid = accid;
newContact.lastname = 'contact'+i;
listcon.add(newContact);
}
if(listcon.size()>0&&listcon!=null)
insert listcon;

}

}

}
```

Comment: what do you need to find in this??your sample code has incorrect systax

Comment: Please edit the title of your question, it must identify the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
trigger ContactCreation on Account(after insert) {
    contact[] records = new contact[0];
    for(account record: trigger.new) {
        for(integer index = 1; record.number_of_locations__c != null && index <= record.number_of_locations__c; index++) {
            records.add(new Contact(LastName='Contact'+String.valueOf(index), AccountId=record.Id));
        }
    }
    insert records;
}
```

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox In this trigger the 2ndline Contact instance "contact[] records = new contact[0];" assumed as contact[0] ,if the record.number_of_locations__c is more number  means then the trigger inserts more number of records or only one records based upon that 2ndline(contact[] records = new contact[0];).

Comment: if i want to show contacts based on number of locations after updating the existing account record what i need to made changes for the above code.

Comment: @Venkatsforce Line 2 initializes an empty array, which is populated with values on lines 3-7 in a loop.

Comment: @user5301 You would need to query the contacts first, then determine how many contacts you need to add/remove.